# How to catch SMPP gateway error type?

Tags: coldfusion, smpp

How can I catch different SMPP error types returned by SMSC server ?

I want to catch result like 0x45,0x01,0x0B,0x58,0x15.... in my code. I can see in eventgateway.log logging the error messages are there, but is there any way I can get immediate error code in my CF page calling sendGatewayMessage() ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using asynchronous or [synchronous mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-77e0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-77df)? With synchronous mode, it should wait for a response and return an error if any *"[in] synchronous mode ... the sendGatewayMessage function does not return until the gateway gets a response from the SMSC or the attempt to communicate times out. ..If an error occurs, the function returns an error string.*.

Comment: We are using synchronous mode and we receive blank string instead of error message. Because by default sendGatewayMessage() returns MessageId, and in case of error Message Id is NULL.